# Override font tag html with css inline

Tags: html, css, email, fonts, overriding

there is a way to override a  size and face using only css inline, I have a template for an email and it does not render css en head or functions, either javascript. I have something like this.

```
<h1><font face="cursive" size="1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">Prueba de descripción</font></h1>
```

this part is dynamic, the code receives another html codes with  that user creates, i want to maintain my own format.

```html
<div class="all:unset !important;font-family:unset !important;font-size:unset !important;">
  <table style='font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace; font-size:80%'>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>
                    <b>Current Status</b>
                </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>
                    <h1><font face="cursive" size="1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">Prueba de descripción</font></h1>
                </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this. The `!important` **may** or **may not** be necessary depending on your stylesheet. The snippet doesn't need it but I figured I would add it anyway. You could also add a `class`.

```css
font {
  font-family: none !important;
}


/* a way to target only that font if there is more <font> elements */

td:nth-child(2)>span>h1>font {
  font-family: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="all:unset !important;font-family:unset !important;font-size:unset !important;">
  <table style='font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace; font-size:80%'>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>
           <b>Current Status</b>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>
          <h1><font face="cursive" size="1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">Prueba de descripción</font></h1>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```